# Is there any tutorials for making custom sales module in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Hyy,
I am new to odoo. I am currently trying to make a custom sales module, but the codes used are still alien to me. Is there a tutorial or blog regarding this module which explains the codes a bit simpler.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Did you already read this: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: Visit this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDepk0LhVuI&list=PLqRRLx0cl0hoJhjFWkFYowveq2Zn55dhM&ab_channel=OdooMates

Comment: @AdamStrauss 
 I know how to create a module. But the problem is , I was trying to create a replica of sales module, but the code used in xml is not familiar to me.

Comment: @Luuk Yap,already read the documentation.

Comment: then dear watch tutorials to get familiar with xml code